# Using proximity tools in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, proximity

I want to find the minimum distance of each point to its enclosed boundary, I have been trying to use the near tool, but the field is giving 0 as values.

This is a picture of the attribute table.

[image]

Comment: Hey, welcome to GIS SE. Can you include a picture or diagram of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Here is a ![picture of the attribute table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65DfW.png) (converted to comment from a answer by @Samirah)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Special Considerations section of [How proximity tools calculate distance](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/analysis-toolbox/how-near-analysis-works.htm) in ArcGIS reference, "When one feature contains or is within another feature, the distance between them is zero. This means that when a feature is inside a polygon, the distance between the feature and the surrounding polygon is zero." So that appears to be operating as designed.

Would you be able to turn the polygons into polylines and try the Near tool again?